# Error when sending an email using VB Script. Need need to know if anything is wrong with this below code?

Tags: vb.net, scripting

Error message:server rejected sender address 530 5.7.1.Client is not authenticated to send Anonymous Email from

Script Used:

```
Set MyEmail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
MyEmail.Subject="Test Email"
MyEmail.From="test@mail.com"
MyEmail.To="send@mail.com"
MyEmail.TextBody="Test Email"
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp.office365.com"
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=587
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate")=1
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername")="test@mail.com" 
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword")="---------"
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusetsl") = True
MyEmail.Configuration.Fields.Update
MyEmail.Send
Set MyEmail=nothing
```

Comment: Why are you not using the [SMTPClient](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjV37Sp8N7GAhWQGZIKHW8MBn8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.net.mail.smtpclient(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&ei=mTunVZWvJ5CzyATvmJj4Bw&usg=AFQjCNH6iW2m1hE1qGnUZAaBASr3Bgce5Q&sig2=wEZMKvOUk9epct77VpaXnQ&bvm=bv.97949915,d.aWw) Class?

Comment: @OneFineDay, I am new vb scripting. tell me how to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Changing the Port Number to 25 solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm , maybe you can use this source from me

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Public Class Form1

        Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()
        smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com ", "pass")
        'using gmail
        smtpServer.Port = 587
        smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
        mail = New MailMessage()
        mail.From = New MailAddress("From@Gmail.Here")
        mail.To.Add("To@Gmail.Here")
        mail.Subject = "Your Subject"
        mail.Body = "Text Message Here"
        smtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Comment: I am new to vb scripting. Can you tell me how to execute this? Earlier I was just saving the file as .vbs and running it.